27in iMac running at 100% CPU usage resolution
How do I resolve 100% CPU usage on my late 2012 27in iMac running MacOS Catalina? The processor is a he processor is a 3.2GHz quad-core intel core i5 with 24GB RAM.

Please edit your question to include details such as what you are doing on the Mac and why this shouldn't result in a high CPU usage. Further, describe whether you have done any kind of changes to your Mac or whether some kind of damage is known. Be as precise and concise as possible.
